# What type of SSD does macbook pro 2015 use?

Tags: ssd

I want to upgrade the ssd from my macbook pro.
What type of SSD do I need to buy?

Comment: A snarky answer would be "whatever SSD you can return if it doesn't work when you install it" but we don't generally accept hardware shopping questions here. Is there something you can't research at https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc and https://www.macmemory.com/pages/ssd  or is this really just about shopping for parts?

Comment: i wasnt looking for a shopping advice. i just want to know the type of SSD to look for as opposed to a brand

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a part like this, but you should check your exact Mac model number with the compatibility list. If you browse by interface or size, keep in mind that if the firmware on the drive isn't equivalent to what Apple sources internally, your part might physically fit but the RAID controller and firmware might result in errors or failure to operate.

- https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSDAB2MB02/

I would recommend partnering with a shop that can provide pre- and post- sales support since Apple doesn't publicly disclose what specific vendors, chipsets and firmware levels it supports. Basically, multiple parts and vendors might be inside any given MacBook 2015 so buying non-apple parts might require a return or two if the vendor doesn't get you a 100% compatible part.